# Problemas con la colisión de objetos

Tags: javascript

Buen día, como indica el titulo, estoy teniendo problemas en la colisión de objetos, lo que pasa es que quiero que me envíe la alerta para así poder crear un evento y añadir un sistema de combate, lo que pasa es que cada vez que me posiciono en el bush no pasa nada ya que no colisiona, recurro a ustedes dioses del olimpo como me pueden indicar que parte estoy haciendo mal en la función in_bush, o si hay que crear una "const" de bush para darle valores y pasarlos por parámetros, mi código está en javascript:

```
const player = document.querySelector('.player')
const bush = document.querySelector('.sprite-bush-1')    


const player_pos = {
    x: parseInt(window.innerWidth /2),            
    y: parseInt(window.innerHeight /2)
}
const player_vel = {
    x: 0,                                           
    y: 0
}

function walk(){
    player_pos.x += player_vel.x;
    player_pos.y += player_vel.y;                   
    player.style.position = "absolute";
    player.style.left = player_pos.x +'px';
    player.style.bottom = player_pos.y +'px';
    requestAnimationFrame(walk)                     
}
walk()

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){     
    if(e.key == "ArrowUp"){                         
        player_vel.y = 3                            
        player.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/RolGame/static/img/mov_back.png")'
    }
    if(e.key == "ArrowDown"){
        player_vel.y = -3
        player.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/RolGame/static/img/mov_front.png")'
    }
    if(e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
        player_vel.x = -3
        player.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/RolGame/static/img/mov_left.png")'
    }
    if(e.key == "ArrowRight"){
        player_vel.x = 3
        player.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/RolGame/static/img/mov_right.png")'
    }
    player.classList.add('active')                  
})
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    player_vel.x = 0                                
    player_vel.y = 0
    player.classList.remove('active')
})

function in_bush(player, bush){
   if (player_pos.x + player.style.width >= bush.style.x &&
       player_pos.x <= bush.style.x + bush.style.width &&
       player_pos.y + player.style.height >= bush.style.y &&
       player_pos.y <= bush.style.y + bush.style.height) {
       alert("i am here in the bush")
    }
}
in_bush()
```

*El código de mi css *

```
.player{
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("/RolGame/static/img/mov_front.png");
    background-size: 240px, 100px;
    background-position: 0px 0;
   /* z-index: 10; */
}
.player.active{
    animation: walking .6s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes walking{
    0%, 32%{
        background-position: -80px 0;
    }
    33%, 65%{
        background-position: -160px 0px;
    }
    66%, 100%{
        background-position: 0px 0px
    }

}
.sprite-bush-1{
    position: absolute;
    width:312px;
    height:332px;
    left:900px;
    top: 300px;
    background: url("/RolGame/static/img/bush_background.png");
}
```

Comment: Se te coló un > en `bush.style.y > bush.style.height`. ¿Será eso? Intuyo que debería ser un +. Por cierto, será mejor si creas una función para cualquier tipo de colisión entre cuadrados (**AABB**). La mayoría de colliders suelen ser cuadrados. Entonces podrás reutilizar el código.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda del >, se me paso, aún continua con el problema, voy a intentarlo como me sugieres, feliz día Mateo